# Gwt problem:how to change textbox value in hypeperlink 

Tags: gwt-ext

in popup panel, i'll take a textbox n i want in button click event it will convert in hyper link.............

Comment: Have you tried anything ? What errors are you getting ?

Comment: Are you the same user " monica bubna"